# DAE files image texture doesn't show up in Aframe when exported from Maya

Tags: textures, aframe

I've exported an .dae file with an image texture from Maya. But when that .dae file is used with Aframe, the image texture does not appear, and you can only see the base material.

What exporter can I use with Maya that will fix this problem?

Below is the same .dae file in PSD, and Aframe:

[image: texture do not show up in Aframe]

UPDATE:

Injecting the model as a Threejs.json via a script works, but kinda defeat the purpose of using AFrame.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RsMA.jpg)

Comment: Note that there are some resources for troubleshooting models here: https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/models.html#troubleshooting

Comment: One extra suggestion: try converting your DAE to glTF using [this tool](https://cesiumjs.org/convertmodel.html), and then loading it with the `gltf-model` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume You added Your collada ( dae ) model like presented on the aframe docs:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="head" src="/path/to/head.dae"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity collada-model="#head"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

To texture the model, You either need to:
1. Make a reference to the texture in the material of the entity.
In `<a-assets>` make an img reference: `<img id="texture" src="head.jpg">` then in Your entity declare the material:

```
<a-entity collada-model="#head" material="#texture"></a-entity>
```

2. upload Your model with the texture to clara.io, convert it to a json(threejs) model, and make sure the references in the json file are correct, then load the model on the `<a-scene>`. I did it by placing a script in a registered 
component:

```
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            objectLoader.load("untitled-scene.json", function ( obj ) {
                sceneEl.object3D.add( obj );
                obj.scale.set(10,1,010);
                obj.rotation.set(0,179,0);
                obj.position.set(0,0,10);
            } );
```

If the issue still happens, please provide more information about Your code.
NOTE: i often received .tga textures, make sure its a .png or .jpg, .tga's won't work if You won't use a tga loader as kevinngo explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433713/why-does-my-obj-mtl-model-material-show-up-as-black). Nonetheless if it's a tga issue, the head would be black as noted in the link.

Comment: Hi Piotr, thank you for your help.

Step 1 did not work. Step 2 did work. But that's kind of a work around of AFrame so not sure what to think. =)

Comment: You can also load three.js models using an A-Frame component: check out `json-model` and `object-model` in the aframe-extras package. Here's an example: http://sandbox.donmccurdy.com/animation

Comment: Suggestion (1) will not work unfortunately. The `material` component sometimes works with OBJ models, but generally doesn't work with 3D models at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it means i was lucky for a long time :)

Answer (score 0):

When I export my model from Cinema 4D to collada 1.5 it comes out without textures, but when I export collada 1.4 it is textured in a-frame!

Maybe this helped!