# A-frame not loading materials

Tags: object, aframe

I understand this seems to be a common problem for beginners in A-Frame but I'm struggling to get a material onto a model in this. I can successfully get the model in but it always comes out grey with the console telling me:

"Material component properties are ignored when a .MTL is provided".

[Grey...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7sUb.png)

I've made this in Blender with a simple glossy material and exported it as an .obj with relative paths (that's what is recommended yes?)

I'm not familiar with .mtl or .obj files but is there something else I have to do to them to get them working in A-Frame? Or is it an issue with the code or CORS?

html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a-scene stats>
            <a-assets>

                <!--Not working-->
                <a-asset-item src="meh.obj" id="meh"> </a-asset-item>
                <a-asset-item src="meh.mtl" id="mat"> </a-asset-item>

            </a-assets>

            <a-obj-model src="#meh" mtl="#mat" position ="0 0 5"> </a-obj-model>

        </a-scene>
    </body>
    </html>
```

obj

```
    # Blender v2.78 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
    # www.blender.org
    mtllib meh.mtl
    o Cube
    v 1.083111 0.312460 -1.083111
    v 1.083111 0.312460 1.083111
    v -1.083111 0.312460 1.083110
    v -1.083110 0.312460 -1.083111
    v 1.083111 3.724101 -1.083110
    vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
    vn 1.0000 -0.0000 0.0000
    vn -0.0000 0.5360 0.8442
    vn -0.8442 0.5360 -0.0000
    vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
    usemtl RedGloss
    s off   
    f 1//1 2//1 3//1 4//1
    f 1//2 5//2 2//2
    f 2//3 5//3 3//3
    f 3//4 5//4 4//4
    f 5//5 1//5 4//5
```

MTL:

```
# Blender MTL File: 'None'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl RedGloss
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: We've fixed the material warning in A-Frame master, but it shouldn't affect the MTL being loaded in. You could try https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/149586a/dist/aframe-master.min.js, but I don't think it'll fix the issue. You can try converting it to glTF too https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/obj2gltf and using `<a-gltf-model>`

Comment: I've tried using a gltf a few times and I'm not sure if it's the Blender export settings or loading problems (maybe a mixture of both) but I've never managed to get a gltf working. I've got the mesh of obj and if i recall correctly.                                                                                                               I tried using your js reccommendation there, it is intended to go alongside with the https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/...script yes? errors seem to pop up when I use both together but works fine alone. Didn't change anything on obj, still testing more stuff

Answer (score 1):

The three.js obj/mtl loaders don't work well, and MTL files generated by Maya ( maybe even blender ) are unreadable for the loaders, which are implemented in the a-frame material system. Multiple problems reported [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1250), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451617/dae-files-image-texture-doesnt-show-up-in-aframe-when-exported-from-maya).

The easiest way, as I suggested in one of the links, is uploading the model to clara.io, and downloading an three JSON model, as it seem to work very good. Maybe You can try with [Don McCurdy's loaders](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders)(though they seem to be more for the geometry, not for the material), but it seems, 3D formats are quite complicated. 
 Since You do it exactly as suggested in the [official docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/obj-model.html), I wouldn't say there's something wrong with Your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this at the minute. Will let you know how it goes....

Comment: try my second suggestion ( the threejs format ) from the second link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451617/dae-files-image-texture-doesnt-show-up-in-aframe-when-exported-from-maya

I got my model butchered once, but in general it works ( remember, that you may accidentally export a camera/light if on the blender scene )

Comment: So far I've tried to get the hang of clara.io but I'm having trouble understanding exporting a json file ( I assume I don't go for the deprecated option). I've also put an add on to my blender to try and export my model there as a json and it has exported it but noting comes up when in A-Frame unfortunately.

Comment: did You try to use the loader as descibed in the linked case for your three.js model ?

Comment: May sound a bit stupid but I've been struggling to get the scripts working properly. Couldn't seem to load to Don's script online so I downloaded it and put the master-min.js in the code but errors were coming up when I used it with the aframe.io script. Tried using just the loaders js with aframe.io script but errors come up saying 'module is not defined'. I may be missing something obvious, haven't coded in a good while, but can't think of anything here.

Comment: One thing I have recently realised is that I think the obj/mtl is linked and working to some extent. Without the mtl included in the code it looks like the defualt grey material but with the mtl it looks a bit glossier but still grey. Seen as I used a glossy material in Blender I'm gonna assume it works with some elements of the mtl file....

Comment: Can't You export a jpg texture, and set the three.js material to whatever You want it to be (emissive, metallic etc) ? as You said, it works to some extent, but it seems to be a bad idea to rely on at the moment