# In Aframe - Maya exported obj models have black textures

Tags: export, maya, modeling, aframe

I'm a 3d artist and my exported models have black textures in Aframe.
I don't know what I did wrong. I use MAYA to export a simple texture with a MTL file and obj model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the official FAQ on working with [models](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/faq.html#which-3d-model-formats-work).

To get Your model to work 'as expected', You need to use either format:

- .gltf
- three.js JSON

I'd recommend .gltf, since there are multiple working exporters, like [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF) from khronos group.

Furthermore, a-frame's Don McCurdy has a wonderful set of [loaders](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders).

---

Sometimes You can get .obj's to work and render textures @ the material component , but they can be unpredictable, like Don said in a [comment to this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451617/dae-files-image-texture-doesnt-show-up-in-aframe-when-exported-from-maya/44455394#44455394).

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 things, somehow in my mtl file the kd(duffuse) was set to 0.0 0.0 0.0 
on export, i put it on 1.0 1.0 1.0.
Second, additional to direction light the ambient light in a-frame showed my texture.