# 3D Objects with no texture in WEBVR

Tags: 3d, aframe, webvr, 360-virtual-reality

Well, we have some 3D objects and we've tried to insert them into the WEBVR platform, while the videos are playing in the background. The 3D objects are in DAE format, but it is not working. They are  white with no texture,. I guess we need them in OBJ and .MTL formats so we have them with texture. Am I right:? How do we insert them in the code? With the collada-model we tried it worked.

Comment: I recommend exporting your model to OBJ or glTF formats. To load them in your A-Frame scene use the `obj-model` and `gltf-model` components: https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/models.html

Answer (score 0):

As Diego Marcos wrote in the comment, it is recommended to use the glTF format, or the three JSON. You can see the a-frame team mentions them in their [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/faq.html#which-3d-model-formats-work).

As for the glTF, if You are using blender, there is a [really simple exporter provided by khronos group](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter). There are also [instructions for Maya LT](https://www.khronos.org/news/permalink/exporting-gltf-2.0-from-maya-lt), but I have never tried it.

As for three.js JSON, [clara.io](https://clara.io/) allows you to upload models, and export to a three.js json format. Personally, I prefer the glTF, as i had little to none issues with them.

Other formats are not easy to handle, and having an obj + mtl may not solve Your problem. Although a-frame's Don McCurdy made lots of [loaders](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders), he also seems to recommend the glTF format, like he did in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451617/dae-files-image-texture-doesnt-show-up-in-aframe-when-exported-from-maya/44455394#44455394)