# Loading 3D file using A-frame

Tags: aframe

I want to load .obj file in a-frame scene. But sometimes file does not appear. And sometimes file is appeared but color does not appear. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to load .obj's, obj + mtl won't work properly.

A-frame recommends the .gltf format on their official [website](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/models.html).
From my own experience, it's a good idea to convert Your model to the .gltf format.

You can find the blender exporter [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF).

Comment: is there any tool to convert?

Comment: @FalakSabbir if You're using blender, try the linked khronos group exporter, if you use Maya, Don McCurdy described it [here](https://www.donmccurdy.com/2017/06/27/exporting-gltf-2-0-from-maya-lt-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, load your asset .obj and .mtl to your assets.

```
<a-assets> 
  <a-asset-item id="asset-obj" src=".../asset.obj"></a-asset-item>
  <a-asset-item id="asset-mtl" src=".../asset.mtl"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
```

From there, you can then load in your asset. (If you have borrowed an asset from someone and want to change the color yourself then don't apply the .mtl file)

```
<a-entity obj-model="obj: #asset-obj; mtl: #asset-mtl">
```

If applying a custom color:

```
<a-entity obj-model="obj: #asset-obj" material="color: red">
```

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the material component wont work if you want to apply a custom texture/image to the entity. However it does work fine when it comes to applying a flat colour to an object.

Comment: Don McCurdy claims, that the material property won't always work with obj models, check out his comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451617/dae-files-image-texture-doesnt-show-up-in-aframe-when-exported-from-maya/44455394)

Comment: The component wont work for textures, env maps, images, etc. However it works fine when it comes to simply applying a flat colour, such as above.

Comment: At least such is my personal experience