# Problems running a simple OBJ file with A-Frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

Hello I'm trying to run a simple OBJ file that was render on blender, using the A-Frame Library, but the result comes full of bugs 
That's the code there I'm using as you can see it's a really simple code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/aframe.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>

 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <a-scene inspector="url: javascripts/aframe-inspector.min.js">
  <a-assets>
   <!-- 3d models -->
   <!-- <a-asset-item id="ead-obj" src="models/Objetos/ead.obj"></a-asset-item>
   <a-asset-item id="ead-mtl" src="models/Objetos/ead.mtl"></a-asset-item> -->

   <a-asset-item id="predio-obj" src="models/Teste/campus2.obj"></a-asset-item> 
   <a-asset-item id="predio-mtl" src="models/Teste/campus2.mtl"></a-asset-item> <- Here I set the items and the path.

   <!-- <a-asset-item id="sala01-obj" src="models/Objetos/sala01.obj"></a-asset-item>
   <a-asset-item id="sala01-mtl" src="models/Objetos/sala01.mtl"></a-asset-item>

   <a-asset-item id="sala02-obj" src="models/Objetos/sala02.obj"></a-asset-item>
   <a-asset-item id="sala02-mtl" src="models/Objetos/sala02.mtl"></a-asset-item> -->

   <!-- checkpoint -->
   <a-mixin id="checkpoint"></a-mixin>
         <a-mixin id="checkpoint-hovered" color="#6CEEB5"></a-mixin>
  </a-assets>

  <a-camera 
    position="0 10 25"
    camera="userHeight: 16"
                universal-controls="movementControls: checkpoint"
                checkpoint-controls="mode: animate; animateSpeed: 40">
   <a-cursor></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>

  <a-entity>

   <a-entity
    id="Predio"
    position = "10 20 0"
    obj-model="obj: #predio-obj; mtl: #predio-mtl"
    checkpoint="offset: -15 6 15"
    scale = "3 3 3"
    >
   </a-entity> <- and here I put the entity as is recommended on A-frame.

   <a-entity
    id="Ead"
    position = "10.5 20 0"
    obj-model="obj: #ead-obj; mtl: #ead-mtl"
    checkpoint="offset: -24 5 10"
    scale = "3 3 3"
    >
   </a-entity>

 <!-- <a-entity
    id="Build"
    position = "18 20 0"
    obj-model="obj: #sala01-obj; mtl: #sala01-mtl"
    checkpoint="offset: 0 10 20"
    scale = "3 3 3"
    >
   </a-entity> -->

   <a-entity
    id="Sala02"
    position = "25 20 0"
    obj-model="obj: #sala02-obj; mtl: #sala02-mtl"
    checkpoint="offset: 15 5 15"
    scale = "3 3 3"
    >
   </a-entity>
  </a-entity> 

  <a-sky color="lightblue"></a-sky> 
 </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

So I run this code and what it shows it's this:

This is the result that is bugged:

[image]

it's a small file only 4MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the glTF format. It is also recommended by the a-frame team in the the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/models.html). It's made specifically for webGL engines.

The exporter is a simple blender [plugin](https://www.khronos.org/gltf/), if you want an animation in your model try this [one](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf).

As for the obj / mtl combo - the mtl file is rarely working, and using the `material` component on an .obj is not guaranteed to be working, as noted by a-frame's Don McCurdy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451617/dae-files-image-texture-doesnt-show-up-in-aframe-when-exported-from-maya), where he also recommends the glTF format.

Comment: Hey dude thanks very I use the glTF format and  work very well, thank you very much

Comment: @GuilhermeMarques glad i could help :)